# Laravel: Left join sql error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have written a sql query using Laravel, but I am not understanding, why the error is creating! The codes are given below,

The join operation:

```
MeetingRoom::select('mr_id')

    ->leftJoin('meetingroomhistory',function($join)
    {
        $join->on('country','=',Session::get('country'));           
        $join->on('location','=',Session::get('location'));
        $join->on('building','=',Session::get('building'));
        $join->on('floor','=',Session::get('floor'));
        $join->on('name_of_mr','=',Session::get('room'));
    })
    ->where('meetingroom.id','=','meetingroomhistory.mr_id')
     ->get();
```

The error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Bangladesh' in 
'on clause' (SQL: select `mr_id` from `meetingroom` left join
 `meetingroomhistory` on `country` = `Bangladesh` and `location` = 
`Dhaka` and `building` = `Uttara` and `floor` = `3` and `name_of_mr` = 
`1` where `meetingroom`.`id` = meetingroomhistory.mr_id)
```

But if I run the query manually to change this syntax `Bangladesh` to "Bangladesh" using phpmyadmin so it runs well and show me the result. Please someone let me know, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've confused the where part and the join part.

`$join->on($x, $y)` statements are for connecting your tables together. Both `$x` and `$y` should be names of columns in your tables - that is why Laravel is adding backticks to them.

`$where()` statements are for comparing with values that you supply. Your `Session::get()` calls indicate that's what you're doing.

Here's a suggested rewrite, but it may need to be tweaked to suit your exact needs.

```
MeetingRoom::select('mr_id')
    ->leftJoin('meetingroomhistory', 'meetingroom.id', '=', 'meetingroomhistory.mr_id')
    ->$where('meetingroom.country','=',Session::get('country'))
    ->$where('meetingroom.location','=',Session::get('location'))
    ->$where('meetingroom.building','=',Session::get('building'))
    ->$where('meetingroom.floor','=',Session::get('floor'))
    ->$where('meetingroom.name_of_mr','=',Session::get('room'))
    ->get();
```

I assumed the country, location, etc. columns are part of the meetingroom table, if not you can just change them to `$where('meetingroomhistory.country', ...)` and so on instead.

Finally, I'm not sure why you're selecting only one value, but of course, that's up to you. If you need only a single cell, you can use `pluck()`, and if you need a lot of single results you could do `lists()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this.

```
    MeetingRoom::select('mr_id')
      ->join('meetingroomhistory', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('meetingroom.id','=','meetingroomhistory.mr_id')
            ->where('meetingroomhistory.country','=',Session::get('country'));           
            ->where('meetingroomhistory.location','=',Session::get('location'));
            ->where('meetingroomhistory.building','=',Session::get('building'));
            ->where('meetingroomhistory.floor','=',Session::get('floor'));
            ->where('meetingroomhistory.name_of_mr','=',Session::get('room'));
        })
     ->get();
```